# How to use Angular Schematics not published but in project direclty

Tags: angular, build, angular-schematics

I want to create an Angular Schematics to create some components and make it easier to develop my application. The problem is that i don't want to publish it, i want to use it "as it is" in my project. Basically my project have this structure :

```
- dist
- nodes_modules
- projects 
        - lib-common
        - lib-user
        - lib-XXX
        - ...
- src
...
```

And i want to do that structure :

```
- dist
- nodes_modules
- projects 
        - lib-common
                - schematics
        - lib-user
        - lib-XXX
        - ...
- src
...
```

My goal is to develop in other libs (like `lib-user` for ex) and use the schematics created in `lib-common > schematics`.

For information the schematics i'm trying to create is a schematic that will create several components, kind of like what the command `ng generate component XXX` does.

I read a lot about schematics, and i understand how they work. But i can't understand how to build them (and if it is necessary ?) or how to use them. I very lost because the structure of my project is complex: The main application have package.json, the library also, do the schematic also need one ? What about nodes_modules ?

For now, every tutorial i read told me to build my application and schematics seperatly, and i managed to do that and export the built schematic to the dist folder, but i don't know how to user it because the tutorial told me to publish it and i don't want to do that.

Every information you have regarding that will be useful to me so thanks, if i have to sum up i'll ask :

- Can i use a schematic without building it ? (i guess not but i ask anyway)
- How do i use it ? (I guess i have to point at the built schematic but i don't know how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to build schematics, actually you can compile it in place using `tsc -p tsconfig.json`.

Then you can run it using `schematics <schematics project path>/src/collection.json:<name> --project <target project>`

Comment: When i try that it says Collection <path-to-collection> cannot be resolved .. (i typed the right path)

Comment: If i am in the schematics dir i can type "schematics .:grid-list" and it works, but if i'm at the projects root and i type "schematics <path to previous dir>:grid-list" it doesn't work. How so ? what can i do ?

Comment: <path-to-collection? is a placeholder, you have to type in actual path

Comment: yes i know. I made it work by doing "npm link" on my built schematic and into the nodes_modules of the application. And then i can do ng g <schematic>:<schematic-name> and it works. But there are so much more that i don't understand

Comment: The <path-to-collection> has to start with `./` for local paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can just build your library and `npm install` the output in your dist folder. This way, it gets declared as a dependency, and you can use the schematics associated with it.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand, build which library ? the lib-common ? and just "npm install" or "npm install XXX" ? where do i npm install ? I see the point you make but i don't understand, please can you be more specific ?